# Neo4j browser freezes the whole system

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, neo4j

I'm using an embedded Neo4j instance in my Spring Boot project (I'm using Spring JPA and Neo4j separately and I'm not using Spring-Boot-Neo4j stuff) and I want to visualise the graph I build using the Neo4j browser that I downloaded from [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser) with the addition of a custom init.coffee that allows it to display images inside the nodes

This is the code I use in order to build my graph. The "buildGraph" function is executed when a request is being received by one of my RestControllers

(the reason I include all of my business logic implementation is because it may help detecting relationships/nodes etc being created/handled in a wrong way)

```
@Component
public class GraphBuilder
{
    private String dbPath;
    private int numberOFConnectionsForKeyIndividuals;
    private String neo4jBoltAddress;

    @Autowired
    PersonService personService;

    private final GraphDatabaseService graphDb;

    public GraphBuilder(@Value("${dbPath}") String dbPath,
                        @Value("${neo4jBoltAddress}") String neo4jBoltAddress,
                        @Value("${numberOFConnectionsForKeyIndividuals}") int numberOFConnectionsForKeyIndividuals)
    {
        GraphDatabaseSettings.BoltConnector bolt = GraphDatabaseSettings.boltConnector( "0" );

        this.dbPath = dbPath;
        this.neo4jBoltAddress = neo4jBoltAddress;
        this.numberOFConnectionsForKeyIndividuals = numberOFConnectionsForKeyIndividuals;

        graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
                .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder( new File(dbPath) )
                .setConfig( bolt.type, "BOLT" )
                .setConfig( bolt.enabled, "true" )
                .setConfig( bolt.address, neo4jBoltAddress )
                .newGraphDatabase();

        registerShutdownHook( graphDb );
    }

    public void buildGraph()
    {

        List<Long> AsIDs = new ArrayList<>();

        Map<Long,Long> personIdToNodeMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String,List<Long>> nameToId = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Long,List<Association>> associationsMap = new HashMap<>();

        try ( Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx() )
        {
            Schema schema = graphDb.schema();

            for(Person person : personService.findAllPersons())
            {
                Node personNode = graphDb.createNode(new Label() {
                    @Override
                    public String name() {
                        return "Person";
                    }
                });

                //mapping persons to their respective nodes
                personIdToNodeMap.put(person.getPersonId(),personNode.getId());

                //mapping names to the ids of the persons
                if(nameToId.get(person.getName()) == null)
                {
                    nameToId.put(person.getName(), new ArrayList<>());
                }
                nameToId.get(person.getName()).add(person.getPersonId());

                personNode.setProperty("Name", person.getName());

                for(int a = 0 ; a < person.getAliases().size() ; a++)
                {
                    personNode.setProperty("Alias " + a+1, person.getAliases().get(a).getAlias());
                }

                personNode.setProperty("Additional Name Information", person.getAdditionalNameInformation() != null ? person.getAdditionalNameInformation() : "");
                personNode.setProperty("Id", person.getPersonId());
                personNode.setProperty("Date of Birth", person.getDob() != null ? person.getDob() : "");

                for(int f = 0 ; f < person.getFacebook().size() ; f++)
                {
                    personNode.setProperty("Facebook " + f+1, person.getFacebook().get(f).getFacebookPage() + " (" + person.getFacebook().get(f).getAdditionalFacebookPageInformation() + ")");
                }

                personNode.setProperty("Additional Information", person.getInfo() != null ? person.getInfo() : "");
                personNode.setProperty("image_url","http://localhost:8888/files/"+person.getPictureFilePath());
                personNode.setProperty("Node Type", "Person");

                if(person.getAssociations().size() > numberOFConnectionsForKeyIndividuals)
                {
                    personNode.setProperty("Key_Individual","Yes");
                }

                for(A A : person.getAs())
                {
                    Node ANode = graphDb.createNode(new Label() {
                        @Override
                        public String name() {
                            return "A";
                        }
                    });

                    ANode.setProperty("A", A.getA());
                    //TODO elaborate more on the A with additional properties
                    ANode.setProperty("Node Type", "A");
                    personNode.createRelationshipTo( ANode, EdgeTypes.HAS_DONE );
                    ANode.setProperty("image_url","http://localhost:8888/images/A.png");


                    AsIDs.add(ANode.getId());
                }

                for(Association association : person.getAssociations())
                {
                    if(associationsMap.get(person.getPersonId()) == null)
                    {
                        associationsMap.put(person.getPersonId(), new ArrayList<>());
                    }
                    associationsMap.get(person.getPersonId()).add(association);
                }
            }

            //Validating and building the association edges

            //iterating through the nodes
            for(Long personFromId : associationsMap.keySet())
            {
                //iterating through the associations registered for the node
                for(Association associationFrom : associationsMap.get(personFromId))
                {
                    String personNameFrom = associationFrom.getPersonNameFrom();
                    String personNameTo = associationFrom.getPersonNameTo();

                    //iterating through the persons whose name matches the other end of the association
                    if(nameToId.get(personNameTo) != null)
                    {
                        for(Long personToId : nameToId.get(personNameTo))
                        {
                            //iterating through the associations of the person at the other end of the association
                            if(associationsMap.get(personToId) != null)
                            {
                                List<Association> associationsToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
                                for(Association associationTo : associationsMap.get(personToId))
                                {
                                    if(associationTo.getPersonNameTo().equals(personNameFrom) && nameToId.get(personNameFrom).contains(personFromId))
                                    {
                                        if(nameToId.get(personNameFrom).size() == 1)
                                        {
                                            Relationship relationship = graphDb.getNodeById(personIdToNodeMap.get(personFromId))
                                                    .createRelationshipTo( graphDb.getNodeById(personIdToNodeMap.get(personToId)), EdgeTypes.ASSOCIATES_WITH );
                                            if(associationFrom.getType() != null)
                                            {
                                                relationship.setProperty("Association Type",associationFrom.getType());
                                            }
                                            associationsToRemove.add(associationTo);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            boolean alreadyConnected = false;
                                            for(Relationship rel : graphDb.getNodeById(personIdToNodeMap.get(personFromId)).getRelationships())
                                            {
                                                if( ( rel.getOtherNode(graphDb.getNodeById(personIdToNodeMap.get(personFromId))).
                                                        equals(graphDb.getNodeById(personIdToNodeMap.get(personToId))) ) )
                                                {
                                                    alreadyConnected = true;
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                            }

                                            if(!alreadyConnected)
                                            {
                                                Relationship relationship = graphDb.getNodeById(personIdToNodeMap.get(personFromId))
                                                        .createRelationshipTo( graphDb.getNodeById(personIdToNodeMap.get(personToId)), EdgeTypes.PROBABLY_ASSOCIATES_WITH );
                                                if(associationFrom.getType() != null)
                                                {
                                                    relationship.setProperty("Association Type",associationFrom.getType());
                                                }
                                            }
//                                            associationsToRemove.add(associationTo);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                associationsMap.get(personToId).removeAll(associationsToRemove);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            tx.success();
        }

        Map<Long,List<String>> AToNamesMap = new HashMap<>();


        //detecting names referred in the A's description
        try(Transaction txAs = graphDb.beginTx() )
        {
            for(Long id : AsIDs)
            {
                Node ANode = graphDb.getNodeById(id);
                String A = (String) ANode.getProperty("A");
                for(String name : nameToId.keySet())
                {
                    if(A.contains(name)) {
                        if(AToNamesMap.get(id) == null)
                        {
                            AToNamesMap.put(id,new ArrayList<>());
                        }
                        AToNamesMap.get(id).add(name);
                    }
                }
            }

            List<Long> groupedAs = new ArrayList<>();

            for(Long id : AsIDs)
            {
                if(AToNamesMap.get(id)!= null && AToNamesMap.get(id).size() > 1)
                {
                    for(Long otherAID : AToNamesMap.keySet())
                    {
                        if(id != otherAID && !groupedAs.contains(otherAID) && !groupedAs.contains(id))
                        {
                            if(compareNamesLists(AToNamesMap.get(id), AToNamesMap.get(otherAID)))
                            {
                                Relationship rel = graphDb.getNodeById(otherAID).getSingleRelationship(EdgeTypes.HAS_DONE,Direction.INCOMING);
                                Node otherPersonNode = rel.getStartNode();
                                if(nameToId.get(otherPersonNode.getProperty("Name")) != null && nameToId.get(otherPersonNode.getProperty("Name")).size() > 1)
                                {
                                    otherPersonNode.createRelationshipTo(graphDb.getNodeById(id), EdgeTypes.HAS_PROBABLY_DONE);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    otherPersonNode.createRelationshipTo(graphDb.getNodeById(id), EdgeTypes.HAD_DONE);
                                }
                                rel.delete();
                                graphDb.getNodeById(otherAID).delete();
                                groupedAs.add(otherAID);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                groupedAs.add(id);
            }

            txAs.success();
        }
    }


    private static void registerShutdownHook( final GraphDatabaseService graphDb )
    {
        // Registers a shutdown hook for the Neo4j instance so that it
        // shuts down nicely when the VM exits (even if you "Ctrl-C" the
        // running application).
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook( new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                graphDb.shutdown();
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

When I open the browser and connect it to the bolt that I expose for my embedded neo4j, the browser is able to show all the nodes in my graph database (at the moment less than 100) and it then freezes, causing the entire system to freeze (MacBook Pro 2016, 16GB). This happens around 3/5 times.
I know that the way I make my transactions is not ideal, but as I said all this processing happens before the neo4j browser starts. 
Can you advise me on how to solve this issue? 
Can you see anything in my code (connection left open etc) Is this a known issue for the neo4j browser?